# How to sort nested array of JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I want to sort the below-nested data based on the key.

I have use `.sort()` function but its not working with nested data, i.e: `sortFunction(data,'poolTimeRemain','desc')`

The following is the structure of the JSON that has to be sorted out.

```js
let data = [
   {
      "rows":[
         {
            "poolTimeRemain":"520 hours",
            "industry":"Business & Professional Services"
         },
         {
            "poolTimeRemain":"503 hours",
            "industry":"Business & Professional Services"
         }
      ],
      "button":{
         "rowspan":2,
         "engIds":"a2P3B000000BCOPUA4,a2P3B000000BCQ6UAO"
      }
   },
   {
      "rows":[
         {
            "poolTimeRemain":"420 hours",
            "industry":"Business & Professional Services"
         },
         {
            "poolTimeRemain":"450 hours",
            "industry":"Business & Professional Services"
         }
      ],
      "button":{
         "rowspan":2,
         "engIds":"a2P3B000000BCOPUA4,a2P3B000000BCQ6UAO"
      }
   },
   {
      "rows":[
         {
            "poolTimeRemain":"600 hours",
            "industry":"Business & Professional Services"
         }
      ],
      "button":{
         "rowspan":2,
         "engIds":"a2P3B000000BCOPUA4,a2P3B000000BCQ6UAO"
      }
   }
]
```

Please help.

Comment: Edit your question please, this is barely readable. Also add before and after sort

Answer (score 0):

You just need to access to `rows` and use `.sort` like normal

```js
  let data = [{
    "rows": [{
        "title": null,
        "role": null,
        "relationShip": "Reseller",
        "productFamily": "Google Workspace",
        "poolTimeRemain": "-520 hours",
        "industry": "Business & Professional Services",
        "engId": "a2P3B000000BCOPUA4",
        "country": null,
        "annualRevenue": null,
        "accountId": "0013B00000foEbOQAU"
    }, {
        "title": null,
        "role": null,
        "relationShip": "Reseller",
        "productFamily": "Google Workspace",
        "poolTimeRemain": "-503 hours",
        "industry": "Business & Professional Services",
        "engId": "a2P3B000000BCQ6UAO",
        "country": null,
        "annualRevenue": null,
        "accountId": "0013B00000foEbOQAU",
        "cssclass": "removeTopBorder"
    }],
    "button": {
        "rowspan": 2,
        "engIds": "a2P3B000000BCOPUA4,a2P3B000000BCQ6UAO"
    }
}]

function sortFunction(input, label, dir) {
  if (dir == "asc")
    return input[0]["rows"].sort((a,b) => (a[label] > b[label]) ? 1 : ((b[label] > a[label]) ? -1 : 0))
  else if (dir == "desc")
    return input[0]["rows"].sort((a,b) => (a[label] < b[label]) ? 1 : ((b[label] < a[label]) ? -1 : 0))
} 

console.log(sortFunction(data, "poolTimeRemain", "desc"))
```

Comment: Hi @doan, thanks for your answer, but this will sort only  sub-array, right?, i want, first sub-array will sort and based on 0th index on sub-array, i want to sort parent array of JSON

Comment: @sarveshkumar can you provide more example/test case in your question? Because based on what I saw, 'rows' and 'button' have different structure, 1 is array and 1 is json

Comment: Also, 0th index of sub-array is a json, you can't compare 2 json, only based on key or value

Comment: i have updated the array json example, so expected data will be, 600 hours,520 hours,503 hours,450 hours,420 hours